# TeXstudio preview consistently two slides behind cursor

Tags: texstudio, viewers, ide

I'm working on a set of beamer class slides in TeXstudio. Usually upon compile, the preview slide visible on the right will be at the position of the cursor - instead, for me, it consistently jumps two slides behind. This is reflected in the behaviour of the preview when I enable the "scrolling follows cursor" option - there, too, the preview is always two slides behind where the cursor actually is. If the cursor is on one of the first three slides, the preview stays on the first one.

I get this behaviour on two different machines, so I assume it's not some super specific local bug but something more broad. It also persists independently of whether or not the document is compiled in handout mode.

Any help on resolving this would be very much appreciated, as this behaviour is quite annoying.